# SPARQL query not returning any data

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I am new to RDF, so it will be very nice if you can help me with this!

I am trying to query the *subject* of pickles called "Umeboshi"(It is japanese pickles) as follows:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>       
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT  ?label ?subject
WHERE {

?Thing
       rdfs:label ?label;
       prop:subject?subject.
 FILTER (?label = "Umeboshi")
}
```

This query doesn't give me any data.

As I don't know where to find available properties I am referring to the Umeboshi page on dbpedia http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Umeboshi.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I found:

1. In the page you give, the label is given in English, but in your query you omit the language.
2. `subject` has a different namespace. It is a `dcterm` concept and not a `dbpedia` property.

This leads to the following, changed query, [which results in three bindings](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20onto%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dct%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fsubject%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%3FThing%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%3Flabel%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%3Fsubject.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20FILTER%20%28%3Flabel%20%3D%20%22Umeboshi%22%40en%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on):

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT ?label ?subject
WHERE {

?Thing
       rdfs:label   ?label;
       dct:subject ?subject.

 FILTER (?label = "Umeboshi"@en)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great help!

Comment: @user2267486 Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.